# Punctuation colon

Tags: grammar, punctuation, colons

In case there's a sentence

> The following students are required to submit their assignments by March 15th.

Will there be a colon after 15 or a full stop?

Comment: @Hank I'd assume a list of students would follow the colon.

Comment: @MorganFR True, I did miss that first part haha

Comment: Yes,the details of the students will be mentioned.

Comment: It can be either way, but before the list, a colon will be required to introduce it. A new sentence can be used before the actual list and therefore the first sentence will require a full stop or at least a semi colon. Consider the following: "The following students are required to submit a new paper. (or ;) They will have to do so by March 15th. Those students are: "

Answer (score 1):

As far as there is a list of students to follow, a **colon** is the appropriate punctuation mark here.

**A colon can introduce a list.**

Examples:

***The main points are as follows: (1)...., (2)....., (3).....***

**We need three kinds of support: economic, moral and political.**

(Practical English Usage by Michael Swan)